# Stuck on using Hadoop after completing all the configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I have the running Hadoop environment on localhost with Centos OS. I have installed it following all the steps from different forums and provided documentation.

As per my understanding, I have Hadoop running with three localhost. [Screenshots enclosed[image: ]]

[image]

[image]
Furthermore, the configuration on eclipse has also been done, all the options on eclipse are available like (Map Reduce, Run on Hadoop). After the Map reduce program, the structured files are successfully converted in the unstructured form too.

Now, I am stuck over here of how to proceed with Hadoop? How to retrieve data? What tools / APIs I can use to query the data?

Please share the experience if anyone has worked on it.

Thanks.

Comment: basically I want to anagrammatically access HDFS. so is there any api for this purpose? since, what I know up till now that Hive and Pig are not APIs but individual tools. To be exact I want to know the next step for accessing the HDFS in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats on getting everything setup and running. You should look at either [Hortonworks](http://hortonworks.com/get-started/) or Cloudera. I do not work for either company and don't recommend one over the other, but each will have examples and tutorials that go beyond installation and configuration.

Specifically you need to look at [Hive](http://hive.apache.org/) and [Pig](http://pig.apache.org/) in order to work with Data in HDFS. Hive offers a Query Language in HiveQL that allows you to query and work with data in HDFS or in HCatalog. Pig is a scripting language that will also allow access to data in HDFS.

Start with the above references and you will find additional examples and tutorials within those websites.

Enjoy,
Pat

Comment: basically I want to anagrammatically access HDFS. so is there any api for this purpose? since, what I know up till now that Hive and Pig are not APIs but individual tools. please correct me if I'm heading wrong.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by anagrammatically access HDFS, but there is a Hadoop API reference as well as Hive API references. You need to extend or create your HDFS access using these API's... You're at the Google around the Apache project phase until you actually have some code to work through on this site. That is why your Question is on hold, it's not a question that works well on StackOverflow. BTW, Install Hive and Pig so you have those Jar's and you will have all the packages needed to start. You already have the Hadoop and HDFS packages.